# Make control visible in Storyboard designer

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I have a project from some month ago. Since all the updates and since someone else has modified some code I can not change the position of the button anymore.

How to make GUI controls editable in new XCode?

The codebehind `MainController.m` file is empty. No position and only default class code in it.
Where are my controls in designer to arrange the position?

[image: XCode Gui problem1[![][1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZMaH.jpg)
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBEBY.jpg)

No GUI editable
[image: constraints]

How result looks on iPhone
[![iPhone view][4]][4]

[image: Only visible if installed is clicked]

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking about. How can a control be not editable?

Comment: Thank you for your time. Problem is, that in new XCode 7 I can not see the controls anymore. I am looking for the GUI where I can select the controls and move it around on the canvas to set position by mouse.

Comment: Could the UI just generated by code? If that is the case, you have to changed to the code.

Comment: If on XCode the UI is generated by code (sure that is possible) it will not show anything in storyboard as I understand. The situation is more in working with the XCode designer I need to learn more about like it seems. For me no logic why all of my controls becomes hidden / disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is related to the version of xcode or any particular update.

It may be that the other developer involved used size classes to make this view for a particular size. If you are not in the view size that they set this for you may not see any of the view elements.

Comment: Good idea. The `ViewController.m` file is empty. If you mean this file, that position is coded in codebehind I could not see anything. Also why is the control not visible in storyboard designer?

Comment: keep in mind, this is just a guess... but do you see the `wAny hAny` at the bottom? Try to resize that and see if things change.

Comment: Very thank you for that guess. I see it. And yes, I am not familar with it and I don't like how it works. I will try to play with it. Thank you!

Comment: You could try turning it off :-)

Comment: It was turned off (light gray) and after checking all variants, it just changes the size but does not show any editable control. Still plain white area without buttons. I also have tried by deleting single buttons and view without luck. Still full plain canvas of view without buttons on it.

Comment: From your screenshots this really does look like a size class issue. Can you go through all the variants of size classes to ensure that the view doesn't render for a different size class? All the UI elements are greyed out, implying they are present but not active for the Any x Any combination. Also, maybe since it was turned off it means you should turn it on.

Comment: All variants without success. But when I click on "Installed" I first time see what you are perfect right, the control becomes to be enabled. Could that help? (screenshot attached at the end in my question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93273/discussion-between-adamt-and-nasenbaer).

Comment: When an item's icon is grayed out in the document outline, as many of the icons are in your screen shots, it means the item isn't installed for the current size class, and the item won't show up on the canvas. So your problem is definitely that your items aren't installed for the wAny/hAny size class.